# paypal gateway has rejected request . Invalid token (# 10410 invalid token)

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, paypal-standard

When i try to place order using paypal payments method i got error like this
paypal gateway has rejected request . Invalid token (# 10410 invalid token). 
i have double checked by backend credential. there is no problem. How to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I modified in the configuration module:

- Backend -> System -> Configuration -> Payment methods -> Paypal -> Advanced Settings -> Enable SSL verification to Yes.

If it does not work I recommend, in paypal account, reset API credentials and update in magento.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this happen when the configuration change has not been updated and was able to fix by flushing the Magento Cache through the admin (both buttons).

Answer (score -1):

Are you using PayPal sandbox? What PayPal checkout method you're using?

Please post the complete error message.

Have a look at [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173066/paypal-express-checkout-10410-invalid-token) question too.

Comment: Paypay sandbox account. and paypay Website Payments Standard payment method.

Comment: Complete error message or a screenshot would do the job.